# Powershell bitwise comparison for robocopy exit codes

Tags: powershell, bit-manipulation, hex

I can't get my head around this bitwise conversion problem.

[Robocopy exit codes](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) don't conform to the normal 0(success), 1(failure) pattern so I want to wrap my robocopy calls in the powershell script below to make my TeamCity build configurations fail or proceed appropriately when robocopy terminates.

That first part was solved using a [tip from the net](http://sqlsolutionsgroup.com/blog/using-robocopy-in-sql-server-agent-jobs/) with: `($LastExitCode -band 24)` which correctly treats exit codes 8 through 16 as failures (1) and all others as success (0).

Now I want to echo a message corresponding to the exit code. How do I convert and round/floor the integer exit code (0 - 16) to its hexadecimal equivalent (0x00 - 0x10)?

```powershell
param(
    [string] $source,
    [string] $target,
    [string[]] $action = @("/MIR"),
    [string[]] $options = @("/R:2", "/W:1", "/FFT", "/Z", "/XA:H")
)
$cmd_args = @($source, $target, $action, $options)
& robocopy.exe @cmd_args
$returnCodeMessage = @{
    0x00 = "[INFO]: No errors occurred, and no copying was done. The source and destination directory trees are completely synchronized."
    0x01 = "[INFO]: One or more files were copied successfully (that is, new files have arrived)."
    0x02 = "[INFO]: Some Extra files or directories were detected. Examine the output log for details."
    0x04 = "[WARN]: Some Mismatched files or directories were detected. Examine the output log. Some housekeeping may be needed."
    0x08 = "[ERROR]: Some files or directories could not be copied (copy errors occurred and the retry limit was exceeded). Check these errors further."
    0x10 = "[ERROR]: Usage error or an error due to insufficient access privileges on the source or destination directories."
}
Write-Host $returnCodeMessage[($LastExitCode <what goes here?>)]
exit ($LastExitCode -band 24)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you do not need to convert it.
You do not need conversion because Hashtable keys are converted to [int] on pre-compiation stage.
If you lookup for $returnCodeMessage.Keys , you will see decimal numbers, not hex numbers

To display all messages you should use

```
$exitcode = $LastExitCode    
Write-Host $( @( $returnCodeMessage.Keys | Where-Object { $_ -band $exitcode } | ForEach-Object {return $returnCodeMessage[$_]}   ) -join "`r`n")
```

IF you want to show Hex-encoded $LastExitCode, do

```
$exitcode = $LastExitCode
Write-Host $('0x' + [System.Convert]::ToString([int]$exitcode,[int]16) )
return $exitcode
```

[String System.Convert.ToString(Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/14kwkz77(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As [filimonic mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24968561/2495), `0x10` and `16` are just different ways of writing the same underlying numeric value (i.e. `0x10 -eq 16` evaluates to `true`), so no conversion is needed.

To display each message in the combined return code, you can test each of the individual flag values in turn:

```powershell
if( $returnCodeMessage.ContainsKey( $LastExitCode ) ) {
    $returnCodeMessage[$LastExitCode]
}
else {
    for( $flag = 1; $flag -le 0x10; $flag *= 2 ) {
        if( $LastExitCode -band $flag ) {
            $returnCodeMessage[$flag]
        }
    }
}
```

For a return code like `0x00` (no change) or `0x04` (mismatch) that contains only one message, we look it up directly. Otherwise, for a composite code like `0x09` (some copied, some not) or `0x13` (some copied, some extras, access denied), we check for each possibility and output those that match.

Also, since "Any value greater than 8 indicates that there was at least one failure during the copy operation", you could use `$LastExitCode -ge 8` instead of `$LastExitCode -band 24` to test for errors.